Wordpress Elementor site containers display wrong in Firefox
I encountered a bug where when using the Firefox browser my Wordpress site built using Elementor was looking differently. Specifically the containers had huge gaps and were on the wrong height on the page. Same issue on mobile view.

Different browsers are different. If you can create a minimal example to exercise a bug, you can file it on Bugzilla.
